# Azure Cognitive Service Speech to text

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on mp3 files using microsoft cognitive services with python, I am having a very unusual problem where the same file with .wav is working but .mp3 file is not working, all though its giving success , printing the duration of mp3 file but doesn't return the text.
I am taking file from azure blob storage container and passing it to the api of cognitive service . my code is following

```
account_name = 'testworkspace'
account_key = 'my key'
container_name = 'test' # for example, `test`
blob_name = 't1.mp3' # for example, `whatstheweatherlike.wav`

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
print(sas_token)
url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)
print(url_with_sas)
subscription_key = 'my key'
service_region = 'eastus' # for example, `eastasia`

def get_token(subscription_key, service_region):
    fetch_token_url = f"https://{service_region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken"
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key
    }
    response = requests.post(fetch_token_url, headers=headers)
    access_token = str(response.text)
    return access_token

access_token = get_token(subscription_key, service_region)


# print(access_token)

endpoint = f"https://{service_region}.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US"

audio_blob_url_with_sas = url_with_sas # it's from STEP 1.
r = requests.get(audio_blob_url_with_sas)


headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;text/xml',
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg; codecs=audio/pcm; samplerate=22050',
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}" # Or just use `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key` instead of `'Authorization'`
}

res = requests.post(endpoint, headers = headers, data = r.content)
print(res.text)
```

I have also change the sample rate as well , but that doesn't work for mp3 file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue with the code snippet you have provided.

Output Image:

[image]

As per the documentation, the default supported audio format is **WAV (16 kHz or 8 kHz, 16-bit, and mono PCM).**

To solve this, you can add a function to convert the mp3 file data in wav format before processing the audio.
Below is the updated script to do this:

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
import  io

account_name = 'testworkspace'
account_key = 'my key'
container_name = 'test' # for example, `test`
blob_name = 't1.mp3' # for example, `whatstheweatherlike.wav`

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
print(sas_token)
url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)
print(url_with_sas)
subscription_key = 'my key'
service_region = 'eastus' # for example, `eastasia`

def get_token(subscription_key, service_region):
    fetch_token_url = f"https://{service_region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken"
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key
    }
    response = requests.post(fetch_token_url, headers=headers)
    access_token = str(response.text)
    return access_token

access_token = get_token(subscription_key, service_region)

#Convert the mp3 content into wav
def  convert_mp3_to_wav(mp3_data):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(io.BytesIO(mp3_data))
    audio = audio.set_frame_rate(16000)
    wav_data = io.BytesIO()
    audio.export(wav_data, format="wav")
    wav_data.seek(0)
    return  wav_data

# print(access_token)

endpoint = f"https://{service_region}.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US"

audio_blob_url_with_sas = url_with_sas # it's from STEP 1.
r = requests.get(audio_blob_url_with_sas)

# Convert the MP3 data to WAV data
wav_data = convert_mp3_to_wav(r.content)

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;text/xml',
    'Content-Type': 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000',
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}" # Or just use `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key` instead of `'Authorization'`
}

res = requests.post(endpoint, headers = headers, data = wav_data)
print(res.text)
```

You can convert this mp3 to wav with `pydub` library.

Make sure to install the packages.

```
pip install pydub ffmpeg
```

Output with updated script:

[image]

You can also checkout [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams?tabs=linux,debian,java-android,terminal&pivots=programming-language-python) documentation which gives more details on how the Speech SDK and Speech CLI use GStreamer to support different kinds of input audio formats (including mp3).
GStreamer decompresses the audio before it's sent over the wire to the Speech service as raw PCM.